# "Action Needed" app won't install to phone after removing faulty SD card

Tags: 8.1, apps, sd-card, nokia-lumia-530

I have a Nokia Lumia 530, and I tried installing the app Trivia Crack to it. It's nothing wrong with the app itself, but the problem is that I had a faulty MicroSD card. So I did what people did when their SD card doesn't function: remove it. I went through and removed it through the Storage Sense. Now when I click on "Trivia Crack: Action Needed", it gives the message that SD card was not found. Well of course, my SD card isn't there. When I had first tried to download the app and it wouldn't install because of the faulty card, my settings were to download the app on to the card. However, through Storage Sense, those settings are disabled now because, well, I have no SD card inserted.

I guess the store still thinks that I'm trying to install it on to the card when I don't even have one installed.

So my question is: how do I install it on the phone itself and not the card?

Or, I guess this might work too: is there a way to clear the store cache? Then maybe I can refresh it and re-install Trivia Crack all over again.

I am trying to avoid a factory reset if that is possible.

Original Post: http://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/341388-app-wont-install-phone-after-removing-sd-card.html?mn_qa=1#post2991832

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried with a different SD card installed?